# converting from a vector of char to a vector of short and a vector of float

Tags: c++, casting, endianness

I have written this program to convert from a char to a short:

```
typedef unsigned char u8;
typedef unsigned short u16;

u16 combine2bytes(u8 a, u8 b) {
    return b | (a << 8);
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<char> cVec{ 'a','r','t','u' };
    std::vector<short>sVec;
    for (auto i = 0; i < cVec.size(); i+=2)
    {
        sVec.push_back(combine2bytes(cVec.at(i),cVec.at(i+1)));
    }
    std::cout << sVec.size() << '\n';
    for (auto i = 0; i < sVec.size(); i++)
        std::cout << sVec.at(i) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

So if I understand, if we have a vector (or an array) of 1 byte data and I want to create a 2-byte vector from that 1-byte vector, I have to read 2 bytes from that 1-byte vector? Is this correct? same goes to float and int; we have to read 4 consecutive bytes?

but if I have to read from file, suppose this is the file:

```
F0 5A 6B A9 4C E3 etc..
```

suppose now that I want to cast it to short, so I have to take: `F0 and 5A` but which one is the LSB and MSB (N.B.: the structure is little Endian)?

And if I have to cast it to a float: how I can cast it so I can get floating point? because if I will cast it to a float, it's similar as I cast it to int? how to get the floating point?

Thanks in advance

Comment: OT: I have to say that  `std::vector<char>` is really the same as `std::string` with a little less functionality.

Comment: I am wondering if this is this XY problem question. Are de-facto simply try to implement serialization?

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi yes

Comment: any reason why you cannot use a library like boost? That will take care for you about every details and it will be cross platform as well. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi I'm using  Niels Lohmann's json library (https://github.com/nlohmann/json)

Comment: is the file that you are reading under your control or it is an external source? in other words, do you write the file a some point in your program and you read it back later or it is an input of some sort?

Answer (score 0):

The famous answer it depends fits here.

1. **MSB/LSB**: It depends on how you stored those bytes, for example if you store the MSB in vector case 0 then when reading you should consider this. You can not guess if you do not have this information.
2. **data type**: It depends on what the data you stored there. For example if it's a float then just do the bit shifing and then cast, you can try that by a concrete example. However, if it's another program who has written those bytes or they're not written on the same architecture, then you should have a protocol that defines which bytes are for the mantissa. again you can not guess if you do not have this information.
3. you code snippet: you should cast the data to short before bit-shifting and ORing it to ensure these operations are performed on 16-bits not on 8-bits data:

   ```
   u16 combine2bytes(u8 a, u8 b) {
          return ((u16)b) | (((u16)a) << 8);
   }
   ```

Comment: I store those bytes from left to right that's mean at position 0 i will have: F0 and at position 1: 5A etc..

Comment: @Gamer lets consider this example `initial_int = 0xF05A` Then if you store it as `bytes_vector {F0, 5A}` you should consider that position 0 holds the MSB  when restoring the `restored_int = (u16)bytes_vector.at (0) << 8 |  (u16)bytes_vector.at (1) ...`

Comment: @Gamer for the function combine2bytes consider renaming it to   `u16 combine2bytes (u8 msb, u8 lsb)` or some thing else that is more consistent.